# Where do I place Swagger-UI in a Rails App with Grape?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, swagger, grape-api

I am re-writing (yeah I know!) a Rails app which is largely API driven, using Grape by Intridea and grape-swagger gem to enable Swagger UI for documentation.

So I have a simple hello world app running.  Seems discoverable from the swagger test, though it's giving JSON parse errors at the moment (I'll look into that next).  I want to put the swagger UI into the Rails app, pointed at the /swagger_doc.json so as I build I can make sure the documentation is building properly right along side.

Where do I put the Swagger UI in the rails app?  Public directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay so I found a couple of snafus that were causing nothing to show when I tried just putting it all in the public directory previously.

```
myapp/public/swagger-ui-1.1.1/files
```

1) I don't know if this SHOULD make a difference but the order in which I loaded the rails app and the grape app in the config.ru seemed to make a difference how the routing was handled ...I need to understand more how that works.  But now the mounted grape app inside routes does what I'd expect.  As a result with the swagger-ui unzipped into public then just going to

```
http://appurl/swagger-ui-1.1.1/
```

gives me the swagger UI.  I'll add more detail to this if there's an more to it.

EDIT: As there will be other users out there like me who need a helping hand here, I'll outline it below.  It's pretty easy:

Create /swagger subdirectories in the asset pipeline - I did it under vendor.  Copy the lib files over from the swagger UI to these subdirectories.  Create a basic docs_controller with an index action (can be empty).  Create a views/docs directory and copy the swagger-ui index.html to it.  Change the stylesheet and javascript calls to asset-tags in index.html.  Add resource route for docs.  Change the discoveryURL in the javascript function calling window.swaggerUI to "http://my.root.url/swagger_doc.json" (ideally from ENV variable).

That's it.  It now just works.  One gotcha I ran into, using my Grape API under an api subdomain was CORS when Swagger was running on docs subdomain.  Easily fixed in Grape by adding something like:

```
before do
  header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://#{ENV["BASE_URL"]}"
  header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT"
  header "Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000"
end
```

to your Grape api.rb.  Hope that all helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easy if you take a look this gem, https://github.com/BrandyMint/grape-swagger-rails

Answer (score 0):

We have to put all the Swagger UI in public directory of rails app.
And use it with below version.

gem 'grape', '~> 0.7.0' 
gem 'grape-swagger', '~> 0.7.2'

because 'grape-swagger' gem does not support with latest version.